# Python capitalizing first letter

Tags: python, capitalize

If I want to Capitalized Just the first letter of inputed string of word and int how can i do it
like:
2Bob SANdy wIwi

output:
2bob Sandy Wiwi

the "b" in Bob should be lowercase in the result

Please need some help here, thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.title()` method on your string.

```
"2Bob SANdy wIwi".title()
```

Comment: thx for the reply ,i've used it before but the output is : 2Bob Sandy Wiwi i need it to be "2bob Sandy Wiwi"

Comment: @BebekAngsa: It works. how did you use it??

Comment: @blue_note, The B on Bob should be lowercase in the result

Comment: word = input("Input Your String: ")
        print(word.title())

Comment: yap thx @JohnLaRooy that is the real problems